# Coprime and Comaximal

Tags: ring-theory

I am studying about the ideals.I have came across two concepts coprime ideals and comaximal ideals. For the first look both have the definition $I$ and $J$ are coprime if $I+J=R$ and same is the definition of comaximal ideals.
My question is whether they imply each other,if yes,how?
If they do not imply each other then what is the difference between these?

Comment: I have heard the terms used interchangeably. The definitions seem to be identical, so it seems like it is simply two different names for the same thing.

Comment: Two ideals A and B in the commutative ring R are called coprime (or comaximal) if A + B = R.  both are the same.